# jQuery toggleclass with cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have this script for animate styleswitcher.But I dont know how can i implement cookies for reaload pages.

```
$("#demo_icon").click(function () {
    if($('.demo_changer').hasClass('active')){
        $('.demo_changer').animate({'left':'-180px'},function(){
            $('.demo_changer').toggleClass('active');
        });
    }else{
        $('.demo_changer').animate({'left':'0px'},function(){
            $('.demo_changer').toggleClass('active');
        });         
    }   
});
```

Thx

Comment: Works perfect. Many thaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [jQuery Cookie Library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) like so:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/yqxfd7qp/3/)**

CSS

```
.demo_changer {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.demo_changer.active {
    left: -180px;
}
```

JS

```
function setMyCookie() {
    myCookieVal = $('.demo_changer').hasClass('active') ? 'isActive' : 'notActive';
    $.cookie('myCookieName', myCookieVal, { path: '/' });    
}

if ($.cookie('myCookieName') == 'isActive') {
    $('.demo_changer').addClass('active');    
} else {
    $('.demo_changer').removeClass('active');
}

$("#demo_icon").click(function () {
    $('.demo_changer').toggleClass('active');
    setMyCookie();
});
```